# Como realizar distribuição de texto em uma linha

Tags: css3

Possuo uma página de detalhes onde o título do produto ao redimensionar o navegador ou visto em um dispositivo móvel o texto fica completamente alinhado a esquerda, gostaria que o alinhamento permaneça mas que texto ficasse melhor distribuído, a estrutura onde se encontra o título é essa:

```
 <div class="one-fourth-pers column-last"><h3 class="entry-title"><?php echo $row_rsProdutos['descricao']; ?></h3></div>

    .one-fourth-pers {
    width: 40.5%;
    float:left; 
    /*max-width: 220px;*/
}
```

Ao tentar alterar o width o conteúdo todo é jogado para baixo.
A página pode ser visto aqui: [Página de Detalhes](http://moveissaobento.com.br/msb/detalhes.php?produto=703&dep=2&sub=8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar um `media-query` quando a página for ser quebrada em várias linhas. Na sua página, parece já existir um `media-query` para telas menores que `767px`:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  // …
}
```

O problema pode ser solucionado adicionando uma regra como:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .one-fourth-pers {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela excelente dica @yamadapc, resolveu o meu problema.

Answer (score 2):

Utilize a propriedade `text-align` - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align).

```css
p {
  padding: 4px 0;
  width: 100%
}

.direita { text-align: right }
.esquerda{ text-align: left  }
.centralizado { text-align:center }
.justificado { text-align: justify }
```

```html
<p class='direita'><b>A direita:</b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc et vulputate diam. Fusce placerat magna nec tellus consequat, a fermentum tellus tincidunt. Sed sed pretium mi. Vivamus efficitur consectetur tortor at pharetra. Etiam id rutrum nisi. Ut elementum lorem ultricies ante tincidunt placerat. Aenean eget ex vitae leo consequat volutpat interdum vel sapien. Phasellus vitae mi ipsum.</p>

<p class='esquerda'><b>A esquerda:</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc et vulputate diam. Fusce placerat magna nec tellus consequat, a fermentum tellus tincidunt. Sed sed pretium mi. Vivamus efficitur consectetur tortor at pharetra. Etiam id rutrum nisi. Ut elementum lorem ultricies ante tincidunt placerat. Aenean eget ex vitae leo consequat volutpat interdum vel sapien. Phasellus vitae mi ipsum.</p>

<p class='centralizado'><b>Centralizado:</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc et vulputate diam. Fusce placerat magna nec tellus consequat, a fermentum tellus tincidunt. Sed sed pretium mi. Vivamus efficitur consectetur tortor at pharetra. Etiam id rutrum nisi. Ut elementum lorem ultricies ante tincidunt placerat. Aenean eget ex vitae leo consequat volutpat interdum vel sapien. Phasellus vitae mi ipsum.</p>

<p class='justificado'><b>Justificado:</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc et vulputate diam. Fusce placerat magna nec tellus consequat, a fermentum tellus tincidunt. Sed sed pretium mi. Vivamus efficitur consectetur tortor at pharetra. Etiam id rutrum nisi. Ut elementum lorem ultricies ante tincidunt placerat. Aenean eget ex vitae leo consequat volutpat interdum vel sapien. Phasellus vitae mi ipsum.</p>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela dica @renan, valeu mesmo, isso vai me ajudar muito.